# Creating if statement inside a variable

Tags: linq-to-entities

I am trying to create an '**if**' statement inside the coding below:

```
    var qisg = new QuoteItemSectionGroup
    {
        SectionGroup = db.SectionGroups.Where(x => x.Name == "Longitudinals" && x.Section == TruckSection.Floor).First(),
        StockItem = quoteItem.Chassis.Longitudinal, <<-- Here
        Quantity = 2,
        Length = globals.FloorCalculatedLength
    };
```

Example:

```
if (quoteItem.Chassis.Longitudinal == "SCH100")
    Stockitem = quoteItem.BodyType.Longitudinal;
```

Is there a way that I might be able to create a method like this in my **var qisg**?

**EDIT**: This is what the code looks like now

```
    var qisg = new QuoteItemSectionGroup
    {
        SectionGroup = db.SectionGroups.Where(x => x.Name == "Longitudinals" && x.Section == TruckSection.Floor).First(),
        StockItem = quoteItem.BodyType.Longitudinal == "SCH100" ? quoteItem.Chassis.Longitudinal : quoteItem.BodyType.Longitudinal,
        Quantity = 2,
        Length = globals.FloorCalculatedLength
    };
```

I'm getting the error:

> Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'TrucksWcf.Models.StockItem' and 'string'

I'm sorry but some of the answers are a bit too complex for me to understand 0_o

**ALSO** Here is an example of another StockItem being assigned to a product:

```
    qisg = new QuoteItemSectionGroup
    {
        SectionGroup = db.SectionGroups.Where(x => x.Name == "Cross Member" && x.Section == TruckSection.Floor).First(),
        StockItem = db.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "SCH075").First(),
        Length = globals.FloorCalculatedWidth
    };
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ: Using a ternary ( ?: ) with LINQ let is not enough, need an "IF" but can't seem to get it to work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11029980/linq-using-a-ternary-with-linq-let-is-not-enough-need-an-if-but-cant)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have said, the conditional operator is perfect if it's a simple *if this..then that... otherwise something else* scenario.

If your conditions are more complex you can create a method which checks the condition and returns the appropriate value. So something like...

```
var qisg = new QuoteItemSectionGroup
{
    SectionGroup = db.SectionGroups.Where(somecondition).First(),
    StockItem = DetermineStockItem(valueToCheck)
    Quantity = 2,
    Length = globals.FloorCalculatedLength
};


public StockItem DetermineStockItem(object param)
{
   // Include complex if and logic here.
   return SomeStockItem;
}
```

**Edit:** I've just seen your update with the error message. It looks like `quoteItem.BodyType.Longitudinal` is of type `StockItem`. Given your last code snippet shows that a `StockItem` has a `StockCode` I think you probably need something like this...

```
var qisg = new QuoteItemSectionGroup
{
    SectionGroup = db.SectionGroups.Where(x => x.Name == "Longitudinals" && x.Section == TruckSection.Floor).First(),
    StockItem = quoteItem.BodyType.Longitudinal.StockCode == "SCH100" ? quoteItem.Chassis.Longitudinal : quoteItem.BodyType.Longitudinal,
    Quantity = 2,
    Length = globals.FloorCalculatedLength
};
```

Comment: Ah, you beat me to exactly the same answer :)

Comment: @amcdermott - Hi and thank you for your comment! :) I need to check that **if** my `quoteItem.BodyType.Longitudinal == "SCH100"` **THEN** it has to choose `quoteItem.Chassis.Longitudinal` **else** it should be `quoteItem.BodyType.Longitudinal`. I also have a small problem where it gives me an error - _Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'TrucksWcf.Models.StockItem' and 'string'_

Comment: If your condition is that simple, then the conditional operator is the way to go, The error you are seeing typically occurs when you are trying to compare two entirely different types - in this case `StockItem` and `string`. Perhaps you need something like `SomeStockItem.Name == "stringToCompare"` - though when comparing stings I think it's better to use the `String` class's `Equals(string)` method.

Comment: @amcdermott - What should I insert then here at the "param"? Also is this about right for conditional operator? 
   `if (quoteItem.BodyType.Longitudinal == "SCH100") {quoteItem.Chassis.Longitudinal} else {quoteItem.BodyType.Longitudinal}
   return SomeStockItem;
}` I am a complete newbie, sorry!

Comment: I've updated my answer - I think you don't need a method to determine the  `StockItem` because your condition is so simple.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [conditional ternary operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zakwfxx4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> The ?: operator can be used as a shortcut for an if...else statement.
>   It is typically used as part of a larger expression where an `if...else`
>   statement would be awkward.

```
StockItem = (quoteItem.Chassis.Longitudinal == "SCH100" ?
  quoteItem.BodyType.Longitudinal : null),
```

The format of the expression, explained:

```
test ? expression1 : expression2
```

- test

  - Any Boolean expression.
- expression1

  - An expression returned if test is true. May be a comma expression.
- expression2 An expression

  - returned if test is false. May be a comma expression.

Comment: Thanks for the correction; can only assume that both `Longitudinal` types are of `string`.

Answer (score 2):

Try with conditional operator(https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx):

```
StockItem = quoteItem.Chassis.Longitudinal == "SCH100" ? quoteItem.BodyType.Longitudinal : null,
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 var qisg = new QuoteItemSectionGroup
    {
        SectionGroup = db.SectionGroups.Where(x => x.Name == "Longitudinals" && x.Section == TruckSection.Floor).First(),
        StockItem = (quoteItem.Chassis.Longitudinal == "SCH100" ? Stockitem = quoteItem.BodyType.Longitudinal : String.Empty),
        Quantity = 2,
        Length = globals.FloorCalculatedLength
    };
```