# Using an 'if statement' correctly in a variable

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-6

I would like to use the **if statement** below to calculate a StockCode for my product, but I am getting the error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'TruckWcf.Models.StockItem' to 'bool'

Now I am a newbie in C# as well as EF6, so I am trying my best to understand what is going on here :P.

```
 var qisg = new QuoteItemSectionGroup
        {
            SectionGroup = db.SectionGroups.Where(x => x.Name == "Longitudinals" && x.Section == TruckSection.Floor).First(),
            StockItem = db.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "SCH113").First() ? quoteItem.Chassis.Longitudinal : quoteItem.BodyType.Longitudinal, // <<-- Here lies my error
            Quantity = 2,
            Length = globals.FloorCalculatedLength
        };
```

Can someone please advise me how to fix this small, yet simple problem. Thank you!

Comment: what do you exactly mean by using `db.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "SCH113").First()`?

Comment: Can you explain (in English, not in code) when exactly you want to return `quoteItem.Chassis.Longitudinal` and when `quoteItem.BodyType.Longitudinal` ?

Comment: I want my **StockItem** to have the value of **"SCH113"** and if it doesn't I need it to move on and get the `quoteItem.Chassis.Longitudinal` value never mind the `quoteItem.BodyType.Longitudinal`

Comment: Is `quoteItem.Chassis.Longitudinal` also of type `StockItem`?

Comment: @DavidG Yes it is :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating if statement inside a variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30751344/creating-if-statement-inside-a-variable)

Comment: @CharlesMager, having thought about it, I agree. This question is really just a request for further help with his first question. So voting to close.

Comment: @DavidArno I saw your first comment and I must confess I didn't read both in huge detail.  The code and the title were almost the same, and the question before that looks very similar too.

Answer (score 1):

[As explained to you in your previous question on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30751344/creating-if-statement-inside-a-variable), the ternary operator takes the form:

```
var x = <some boolean expression> ? <value assigned to x if true> : <value if false>
```

You however are doing:

```
StockItem = db.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "SCH113").First() 
            ? quoteItem.Chassis.Longitudinal 
            : quoteItem.BodyType.Longitudinal
```

In this case `db.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "SCH113").First()` doesn't return a boolean. So you need to fix this expression, presumably by comparing it with some other value.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you need something like this:

```
StockItem = db.StockItems.Any(x => x.StockCode == "SCH113")
? quoteItem.Chassis.Longitudinal
: quoteItem.BodyType.Longitudinal
```

Comment: This is not correct (OP made further clarification in the comments)

Comment: @DavidG, I disagree. According to his comments, 'I want my StockItem to have the value of "SCH113" and if it doesn't I need it to move on and get the quoteItem.Chassis.Longitudinal...', this is *exactly* what he requires.

Comment: I also disagree. From my understanding, this should be correct. But yes, it's not exactly clear.

Comment: Well it's pretty clear when he says "never mind the quoteItem.BodyType.Longitudinal"

Comment: @DavidG, hmm, I now think you are right :) Re-reading it, I think he needs `? quoteItem.BodyType.Longitudinal : quoteItem.Chassis.Longitudinal`.

Comment: @DavidArno Either way it's pretty unclear and (as you pointed out in your answer) should probably be closed as a dupe of his own question.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [`??` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) to choose the value. That essentially say take the first value before the `??` but if it's null, return the value after. Also use `FirstOrDefault` or you may get an exception rather than a `null` return value. Finally removing `Where` as it's simpler to write this way (good spot by @YuvalItzchakov):

```
var qisg = new QuoteItemSectionGroup
{
    SectionGroup = db.SectionGroups.Where(x => x.Name == "Longitudinals" && x.Section == TruckSection.Floor).First(),
    StockItem = 
        db.StockItems.FirstOrDefault(x => x.StockCode == "SCH113") ?? 
            quoteItem.Chassis.Longitudinal
    Quantity = 2,
    Length = globals.FloorCalculatedLength
};
```

Comment: You can also entirely remove the `Where` and use `FirstOrDefault` with the predicate.

Comment: I was thinking of `.Any(x => x.StockCode == "SCH113")`, but this should work too.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov Yup, simpler form is nicer.

Answer (score 0):

`First()` will return an object and not a boolean expression, which is what you need here. So you'll have to make a change which is like this :

Change this line of code :

```
StockItem = db.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "SCH113").First() ? quoteItem.Chassis.Longitudinal : quoteItem.BodyType.Longitudinal
```

To this :

```
StockItem = db.StockItems.Where(x => x.StockCode == "SCH113").First() == null ? quoteItem.Chassis.Longitudinal : quoteItem.BodyType.Longitudinal
```

Now this is just an example describing *what* type of change you would have to make here. I have used `null` here. You can use also use `First().SomeField == somevalue` or anything like that too. Just make sure its a boolean condition and you will be fine with this.

Hope this helps.

Comment: If you want to check for `null` you have to use `FirstOrDefault()`. But instead of the `Where` I'd go with `Any`.